# Document-oriented data abstraction layer for NoSQL (Mongo)?

Tags: mongodb, design-patterns, architecture, data-access-layer, nosql

I'm building a server application that interfaces the world via a RESTful web service and uses MongoDB of storage.  As it happens, the JSON resources of the web service are fairly close to the structure of the BSON documents stored in Mongo.

While I typically use an object-oriented DAO abstraction to hide the details of persistence implementation, it doesn't quite seem to be the best fit in this case since what I really want to do is **fetch a document** from the DB based on a query and **perform a transformation**.  Building an object graph as an intermediary seems excessive.

Does anyone have any recommendations for an abstraction pattern that fits this bill?

**Edit:** Removed 1AM degression about just not using any abstraction and just using the Mongo driver directly.

Answer (score 0):

The level of abstraction is up to you, your needs and your requirements. There are various language specific layers on top of the native MongoDB drivers. It is up to you decide what you need and not to us. We can not give recommendation without more precise and detailed background. If you ask a generic question then you will receive a generic question.

And who gave this +1? For what?